# Which classical Hanafis believed anal intercourse is allowed in paradise?

Tags: sex, jannah, islamic-scholar

In the English abstract to A. Schmitt, *In Liwat Im Fiqh: Männlichen Homosexualität?*, J. Arabic Islamic Studies, 2001-2 ([URL](http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/jais/volume/index.htm); [pdf](http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/jais/volume/docs/vol4/4_schmitt1.pdf)), we have:

> Although in the classical period some Hanafis believed [anal intercourse] to be allowed in paradise, later the Hanafiya narrowed the gap with the other madahib

This leads to the question:

**Question**: Which classical Hanafis believed anal intercourse is allowed in paradise?

The answer to this question is probably in the paper, but it's in German.  [Googling the title](https://www.google.com/#q=Which+classical+Hanafis+believed+anal+intercourse+is+allowed+in+paradise?) of this question doesn't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant passage is on page 30, I'll post my own translation here (I'm a native German). The only changes I made myself are in { }. All other parentheses are as they are in the paper.

> Liwat only contra Deum {= against God} or also contra naturam {= against nature}
>
> Then in Ibn al-Humams commentary we find - without reference to a section by Marginani - a short discussion of the question whether there is liwat in paradise: "It's being said: if it is forbidden for intellectual reasons (aqlan) and because of revelation (sam'an), then it cannot exist (in paradise), and if it is forbidden (only) due to revelation, then it can exist (there). The correct view is that it cannot exist in paradise because God rejected it thoroughly and declared it hateful." {footnote 98}
>
> Ibn 'Abidin discusses this question in Radd al-muhtar, his commentary on Haskafis Durr al-muhtar, which in turn is a commentary on/comments on Mulla Husraws (died 885/1480) Durar al-hukkam {footnote 99}: "His [= Haskafis] saying 'And the liwata does not exist in paradise.' As-Suyuti said [in Nawadir al-aik fi nawadir an-naik]: '[Abu l-Wafa' 'Ali] Ibn 'Aqil [b. Muhammad] al-Hanbali [died 513/1119] said: There was a dispute about this between Abu 'Ali [Muhammad b. Ahmad] b. al-Walid al-Mu'tazili [al-Hanafi died 478/1086] and Abu Yusuf al-Qazwini [az-Zaidi died 488/1095]. Ibn al-Walid said: 'It is not forbidden that that is part of the whole of the pleasures of paradise, because the immoral [part of it] does not exist there. For it is forbidden on Earth because it stifles reproduction and is harmful. And in paradise neither of these apply. And for this reason drinking wine was allowed, because [in paradise] it does not intoxicate, meaning it neither leads to belligerence nor to a (temporary) decrease in intellect. For this reason its consumption was not forbidden in paradise.' And Abu Yusuf said: 'The inclination towards men is a weakness/sickness and it is intrinsically hateful, because (the anus) is a place that was not created for coitus. Therefore it was not allowed in sharia. As opposed to wine, [liwat] does not lose its ritual impurity [in paradise because] paradise is free of weakness/sickness.'" {footnote 100}